# Nonexistence of conformal map from the punctured unit disk to the annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Prove that there is no one-to-one conformal map ($=:f$) from the punctured unit disk $\{z:0<|z|<1\}$ onto the annulus $\{z:1<|z|<2\}$.

Proof. Any holomorphic function from the punctured unit disk to the annulus is bounded near $0$ so can be extended to a function that is holomorphic at $0$. In particular it has a square root as it's a nonzero holomorphic function on a simply connected region. However there is a holomorphic function from the annulus to itself without a square root (for example the identity function). So the punctured unit disk cannot be conformal to the annulus.

Let $\tilde{f}$ be the extension of $f$ on the unit disk $\Bbb D$. I understand the existence of square root $g$ i.e., $g^2 = \tilde{f}$. But I can't see why this implies the existence of a holomorphic function from the annulus to itself (so the contradiction makes sense). Can you explain this?

Comment: Use the inverse to take the identity on the annulus to a bounded holomorphic map on the punctured disc who then had a square root; using now the direct isomorphism transfer the square root to the annulus and get a contradiction

Comment: @Conrad Could you write formally as an answer? I can't understand with that description. So the *inverse* you mean the inverse of $f$?

Comment: done as requested

Comment: alternative argument: let simple $\gamma$ generate the circle with radius $\frac{1}{2}$.  Then the winding number $n\big(\tilde{f}\circ \gamma,0\big)=n\big(f\circ \gamma,0\big)\neq 0$ (for second equality, ref https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521061/show-winding-number-is-non-zero-over-conformal-equivalence/ ) and since $\tilde{f}$ is defined on the disc $B(0,1)$ we apply the Argument Principle to conclude $0\in \tilde{f}\big(B(0,1)\big)= \{z:1<|z|<2\}\cup \{\tilde{f}(0)\}$ but connectivity is preserved under continuous maps so $\tilde{f}(0)\neq 0$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $g:\mathbb D^* \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic and both bounded inferior and superior ($0<m<|g(z)|<M$), then $g$ extends holomorphically to a nonvanishing function on the unit disc, so has a holomorphic square root $h^2=g$

Now if $f :\mathbb D^* \to A$ is a holomorphic isomorphism where $A$ is the annulus $1<|z|<2$ (though any proper annulus will do), then if $I:A \to A$ is the identity function, $I\circ f$ is holomorphic and both bounded inferior and superior on the punctured disc, so has a square root $h^2=I\circ f$ which implies that $I(z)=h^2(f^{-1}(z))=(h(f^{-1}(z)))^2$ so getting the required contradiction as we know that $I$ doesn't have a square root ($k^2=I$ implies $2k'/k=I'/I$ and integrating $0=\frac{1}{2\pi i}(2k'/k-I'/I)$ on the circle of radius $3/2$ we get $0=1$)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it.

By open mapping theorem, $\tilde f(\mathbb{D})$ is open and so $\tilde f(0)$ cannot be on the boundary of the annulus.
Say $\tilde f(0)=b$, since $f$ is a biholomorphism, there exist $a\in\mathbb{D}^*$ such that $f(a)=b$, which means $\tilde f(a)=b$.

Now let $\Delta_0,\Delta_a$ be open neighborhoods of $0$ and $a$ respectively
that are disjoint from each other.
$\tilde f(\Delta_0)$, $\tilde f(\Delta_a)$ are both open neighborhood
of $b$ by open mapping theorem.
Let $\Delta_b\subseteq\tilde f(\Delta_0)\cap\tilde f(\Delta_a)$ be an open
neighborhood of $b$.
Let $\beta\in\Delta_b\setminus\{b\}$.
Then there exist $\alpha\in\Delta_a$ such that $\tilde f(\alpha)=\beta$
and $\gamma\in\Delta_0$ such that $\tilde f(\gamma)=\beta$.
$\gamma\not=0$ because $\tilde f(0)=b\not=\beta=\tilde f(\gamma)$.
So $\gamma\in\mathbb{D}^*$.
This contradict injectivity of $f$ because $f(\alpha)=\beta=f(\gamma)$.